# laravel 5 and mysql relations SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to insert values into my services table and I am getting a error. Its saying that I can not add or update child row .
message:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`adrenaline`.`services`, CONSTRAINT `services_id_produit_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_produit`) REFERENCES `produits` (`id_produit`)) (SQL: insert into `services` (`description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sqslqslk, 2016-04-11 21:02:35, 2016-04-11 21:02:35))
my controller

```
   public function create()
 {
   return view('services'); 
 }

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(serviceRequest $request)
{
    $input=$request->all();
   // dd($input);
   \App\Service::create($input);
}
```

my view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Ajouter une service</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                {!! Form::open(['url'=>'service/store']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('titre', 'Titre:') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('titre',null) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('produit', 'Id produit:') !!}
                        {{ Form::input('number', 'produit',null) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('axe_p', 'Id axe principale:') !!}
                        {{ Form::input('number', 'axe_p') }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}

               {!! Form::textarea('description',null) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::submit('Nouveau service') !!}
                </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
     @endsection
```